# How to change color of a button using RGB values?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a user to select a color from a color dialog box and then have a button recolor to the selected color they choose. Here's my code so far:
For example, if I select red, my message box appropriately says (Red: 255, Green:0,Blue:0) but yet my button turns yellow. I've tried with other colors but it seems random. Please let me know what I need to fix, thanks!

```
 private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog cdlg = new ColorDialog();
        cdlg.ShowDialog();
        System.Drawing.Color clr = cdlg.Color;

        System.String r = System.String.Empty;
        System.String g = System.String.Empty;
        System.String b = System.String.Empty;
        try
        {
            byte red = clr.R;
            byte blue = clr.B;
            byte green = clr.R;
            byte a = clr.A;

            r = clr.R.ToString();
            g = clr.G.ToString();
            b = clr.B.ToString();
            System.Drawing.Color backgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(a,red,green,blue);
            // show the value in message box

            MessageBox.Show("Red :" + r + ", Green :" + g + ", Blue :" + b);
            button14.BackColor = backgroundColor;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            //doing nothing
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am confused, you already have the color object `clr`, why not just pass that to `button14.BackColor`?  Also, please work on these variable names they are not descriptive and it makes your code really bad for reading

Comment: Thanks, macc! That solution did it haha. I was just reusing code I found online trying to see if I could make it work, that's why the names aren't descriptive.

Comment: Why don't you use :  button1.BackColor = cdlg.Color;

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to do this would be to simply use the returned `Color` itself, since you aren't modifying any of the values:

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cdlg = new ColorDialog();

    if (cdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        button14.BackColor = cdlg.Color;
    }
}
```